Running Unity mlagents without a terminal, within a C# script
I am working on an mlagents project, and I am trying to have the Python shell run when the Play button is pressed, rather than enter a command in the terminal. I am running on a Mac and we are planning to port this on a Raspberry Pi. Here's what I have so far. It is not erroring out, but the agents are not doing anything.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bootstrap : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject environment;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        var command = "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/mlagents-learn";
        var scriptFile = "/Users/brennanmoores/Documents/results/configuration.yaml";
        var arguments = "";
        if (FighterAgent.episode == 0) {
            arguments = "--run-id=fighterTest --time-scale=1 --capture-frame-rate=0 --force";
        } else {
            arguments = "--run-id=fighterTest --time-scale=1 --capture-frame-rate=0 --resume";
        }
        
        
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
            FileName = command,
            Arguments = $"{scriptFile} {arguments}",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = false
        };

        using (Process process = new Process()) {
            process.StartInfo = startInfo;
            process.Start();

            while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(output);
            }
            
        }
        
        var env = Instantiate(environment, new Vector2(0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        foreach (var p in processes) {
            try {
                if (p.ProcessName == "Python") {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log(p.ProcessName);
                }
            } catch {

            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}

I tried to move around some commands, including removing WaitforExit() and modifying the fire directories but the AI remains motionless.

id show the window, and also capture stderror, to log, until you know it works :D
